# Using Xubuntu remotely on a linode

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal, linode, xubuntu

I'm ssh'd as root into my linode server and have installed Xubuntu (for Ubuntu 10.04). Now I'd like to use it, but issuing `starts` brings about the fatal error `no screens found`. I've installed and run emacs which appears as a GUI interface with the Terminal (I'm using OS X) window, so how can I do the same with Xubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FreeNX ( http://freenx.berlios.de/ ) is a good solution for remote desktop viewing under Linux - it compresses the X protocol much better than VNC (and is faster than natively piping X protocol over `ssh -X`) - you can even watch videos via it on relatively low bandwidth links. If you install FreeNX then you should be able to configure a Xubuntu session through the client.

Comment: I tried ssh -X and it still did not show anything (Primary device is not PCI
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(EE) No devices detected.)

Comment: so freeNX, when installed, would show the GUI when I ssh'd in?

Comment: I certainly think it's worth a try, yes. Alternatively, look into Xvfb and X11vnc http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb